# Game failed on phone but OK in emulator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am building an AR game using Unity. I tested it on Unity and It's OK with the Emulator. However, when I exported it as an apk and installed it on my Android Phone, the game crashed after level 1. Anyone have a hint?

Here is the code for Timer Countdown. After this, my game crashed.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class TimerCountdownL1Win : MonoBehaviour {
    public int timeLeft = 5;
    public Text countdownText;

    void Start ()
    {
        StartCoroutine("LoseTime");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        countdownText.text = ("00:0" + timeLeft);

        if (timeLeft <=0)
        {
            StopCoroutine("LoseTime");
            countdownText.text = "Time's out!";
            //load to new scene
            Application.LoadLevel("Level 1_Win");
         }
    }
    IEnumerator LoseTime()
    {
         while (true)
         {
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
             timeLeft--;
         }
     }
}
```

Error Code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class GyroCamera : MonoBehaviour {
    private Gyroscope gyro; 
    private bool gyroSupported;
    private Quaternion rotfix; 


    [SerializeField]  
    private Transform worldObj; 
    private float startY; 


    void Start () {
        gyroSupported = SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope; 


        GameObject camParent = new GameObject ("camParent");
        camParent.transform.position = transform.position;
        transform.parent = camParent.transform; 


        if (gyroSupported) {
            gyro = Input.gyro; 
            gyro.enabled = true;


            camParent.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (90f, 180f, 0f); 
            rotfix = new Quaternion (0, 0, 1, 0); 
        }
    }


    void Update () {
        if (gyroSupported && startY == 0) {
            ResetGyroRotation ();
        } 


        transform.localRotation = gyro.attitude * rotfix;
    }

    void ResetGyroRotation() {
        startY = transform.eulerAngles.y; 
        worldObj.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0f, startY, 0f);
    }
}
```

[Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp4Le.png)

Comment: Log exceptions and look the stacktrace as well the error message. It should give you a lead to what's wrong. It's hard to tell what does it since we don't have your whole project exposed, nor does anyone want to read all your code through looking for clues and possible things that could make it crash.

Comment: Sorry I'm a Designer and newbie in Unity. I have updated the Stack Trace as image and the Error Code. It seems wrong here 
        transform.localRotation = gyro.attitude * rotfix;
    }

Comment: use logcat to see exceptions and you might want to add additional debug.log in your code before that. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/135143/40748

Comment: Either `gyro` or `rotfix` (I assume both) are `null`. You should check for that in your `Update` function.